# Как выделить часть текста и сохранить ее в переменной

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

У меня есть такой вот текст (это текст, из которого нужно выделить часть, а не код):

```
<iframe src="https://video.sibnet.ru/shell.php?videoid=3291274/" scrolling="no" allowfullscreen="allowfullscreen" frameborder="0">
```

нужно выделить из него часть, которая написана в `src=""`, а именно - `https://video.sibnet.ru/shell.php?videoid=3291274/`. Каким способом можно это сделать с помощью js?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
function getLink() {
  var iframeTag = document.getElementById("iframe_url").value;
  var src = iframeTag.split('src=')[1].split(/[ >]/)[0]
  alert("Ссылка на видеофайл: " + src)
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="iframe_url" name="iframe_url" value='<iframe src="https://video.sibnet.ru/shell.php?videoid=3291274/" scrolling="no" allowfullscreen="allowfullscreen" frameborder="0">' />
<button id="opener" onclick="getLink()">Получить ссылку</button>
```

Comment: Этот текст - значение, которое вводит пользователь в `input`. Я не могу ему присвоить id

Comment: var src = inputText.split('src=')[1].split(/[ >]/)[0]

Comment: сейчас сделаю пример в ответе

Comment: обновил ответ в качестве кода с текстовым полем и кнопкой, после нажатия которой получите алерт с ссылкой на видео.